# Line Integral of a Vector Field Over a Smooth Curve

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

I am being asked to prove the following:

Suppose that **F**:$\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector field and $C$ is a smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $||\textbf{F}(x,y)|| \leq M$ for every point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $L$ is the arclength of $C$, prove that:

$\mid \int_C \textbf{F} \cdot d \textbf{r} \mid $ $\leq$ $ML$

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out where to start, any redirection would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a version of the triangle inequality. If you're not used to triangle inequality proofs, think about which F makes the integral as large as possible subject to your constraint.

Comment: $|\int_{\Omega}{f}gdx| \leq |f|_{\infty} \int_{\Omega}|g|dx$

Comment: Maybe it would help to remember that $\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r = \mathbf F\cdot\mathbf T\,ds$, where $\mathbf T$ is the unit tangent vector to the curve. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose ${\bf F}=(f(x,y),g(x,y)$ and then
$$ \sqrt{f^2(x,y)+g^2(x,y)}\le M. $$
Let ${\bf r}=(x(t),y(t))$ be the parametric expression of $C$ for $t\in[0,l]$. Then
$$ d{\bf r}=(x'(t),y'(t))dt $$
and hence
$$ \int_C{\bf{F}}\cdot d{\bf r}=\int_0^l(f(x,y)x'+g(x,y)y')dt. $$
Using
$$ |a_1b_1+a_2b_2|\le \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2} $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\bigg|\int_C{\bf{F}}\cdot d{\bf r}\bigg|\\
&=&\bigg|\int_0^l(f(x,y)x'+g(x,y)y')dt\bigg|\\
&\le&\int_0^l\bigg|f(x,y)x'+g(x,y)y')\bigg|dt\\
&\le&\int_0^l\sqrt{f^2(x,y)+g^2(x,y)}\sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2}dt\\
&\le&M\int_0^l\sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2}dt\\
&=&ML.
\end{eqnarray}
Another way to do is to simply use
$$ \bigg|\int_C{\bf{F}}\cdot d{\bf r}\bigg|\le \int_C\bigg|{\bf{F}}\cdot d{\bf r}\bigg|\le \int_C|{\bf{F}}||d{\bf r}|\le M\int_C|d{\bf r}|=ML. $$